# ASP MVC: ViewModel index using master detail linq statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC so please bear with me. I have two models:

```
public class Change
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // more fields
    public virtual ICollection<ChangeHistory> ChangeHistory { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ChangeHistory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ChangeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date {get; set; }
    public Status Status {get; set; }
}
```

Currently, my Changes view simply lists all changes in a table with their details (ID, Title etc.). What I would like is to add several columns from the details table such as Inititiaton Date (Date of the first ChangeHistory item for a given Change) and Current Status & Date (both retrieved from the last ChangeHistory item for a given Change.)

I started by creating a new ViewModel:

```
public class ChangeViewModel
{
    // Take these details from the change record
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        

    // Take these details from the first change history record
    public DateTime InitiationDate { get; set; }

    // Take these details from the latest change history record
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In my ChangesController I got as far as retrieving the Initiation Date before my lack of experience stopped me in my tracks:

```
var ChangeWithStatus = from c in db.Changes
                               from h in db.ChangeHistories
                               where c.ID == h.ChangeID && h.Date ==
                               (
                                   from h2 in db.ChangeHistories
                                   where c.ID == h2.ChangeID
                                   select h2.Date
                               ).Min()

                               select new ChangeViewModel
                               {
                                   // Change details
                                   ID = c.ID,
                                   Title = c.Title,
                                   Description = c.Description,

                                   // Initiation details
                                   InitiationDate = h.Date,
                                   Initiator = h.User,

                                   // Status details
                                   StatusDate = h.Date,
                                   CurrentStatus = h.Status,
                                   User = h.User
                               };
```

I'm wondering if the solution is to retrieve each ChangeHistory record with its own linq statement and then combine them with a third. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't add the answer in your question (that's what the 'Answer' section is for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var changeViewModels = (from change in db.Changes
                        let lastChangeHistory = change.ChangeHistory.OrderByDescending(changeHistory => changeHistory.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                        let firstChangeHistory = change.ChangeHistory.OrderBy(changeHistory => changeHistory.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                        select new ChangeViewModel
                        {
                            ID = change.ID,
                            Title = change.Title,
                            Description = change.Description,
                            InitiationDate = firstChangeHistory.Date,
                            StatusDate = lastChangeHistory.Date,
                            CurrentStatus = lastChangeHistory.Status,
                        }).ToList();
```

Using [let clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) this line:

```
let lastChangeHistory = change.ChangeHistory.OrderByDescending(changeHistory => changeHistory.Date).FirstOrDefault()
```

will give you the last change history for every change.
while this line:

```
let firstChangeHistory = change.ChangeHistory.OrderBy(changeHistory => changeHistory.Date).FirstOrDefault()
```

will give you the first.
Now you have all the data you need and you can select it into ChangeViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I receive the following error:

Comment: An expression of type 'System.DateTime' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<B4C_Workstack.Models.Change>'.  Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Comment: I'm afraid there is a consequential issue:  'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Status' and no extension method 'Status' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\B4C Workstack\B4C Workstack\Controllers\ChangesController.cs

Comment: Can you please try it again now?

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the .ToList() at the end:  'B4C_Workstack.Models.ChangeViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'B4C_Workstack.Models.ChangeViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\B4C Workstack\B4C Workstack\Controllers\ChangesController.cs

Comment: One last try, can you try it now with parenthesis?

Comment: Builds fine, but loading the page produces the following exception:
{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'B4C_Workstack.Models.ChangeHistory Last[ChangeHistory](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[B4C_Workstack.Models.ChangeHistory])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Maybe LINQ to Entities will suppport OrderByDescending with First instead, can you try the edit I did?

Comment: Perfect! Had to replace First() to FirstOrDefault() and now it works beautifully. Just need to put some checks in for null values and it works brilliantly. I'll update the OP with the solution - thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad I could help, writing LINQ to Entities queries can be a little bit tricky at the beginning.